# Show that every induced subgraph of a bipartite graph is bipartite.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that every induced subgraph of a bipartite graph is bipartite.

My try:

Let $G'(V',E')$ be a subgraph of $G(V,E)$.

We know by hypothesis that $V=V_x\cup V_y$ then $V'\subset V_x \cup V_y$

So there are three cases:

Case I: $V'\subset V_x$ and $V' \not \subset V_y$

Then $E'= \emptyset$ and $G'$ would be a bigraph.

Case II: $V'\not \subset V_x$ and $V' \subset V_y$

Analogous to the previous case.

Case III: $V'\subset V_x$ and $V' \subset V_y$

Here is where I'm stock. I know that subgraph would be bipartite but I don't know how to argue it.

Comment: Hint: given a subgraph $G'(V',E')$ consider $V'\cap V_x$ and $V'\cap V_y$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest strategy is a different one.  It is well-known (and easily shown if you didn't know it) that a graph is bipartite if and only if it doesn't contain a cycle of odd length.  Since the subgraph of a bipartite graph obviously couldn't gain a cycle of odd length, it must also be bipartite.